# Go around Circular dependency

Tags: angular, circular-dependency

Is there a better way to go around the circular dependency if component uses the service and the service initializes the component?
what I have done here is, since the component is initialized by the service, I inject the service itself into the component without using angular dependency injection.

> Workspace Service

```
@Injectable()
export class WorkspaceService {
  name = "John";
  constructor(
    private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private injector: Injector
  ) {
    this.appendWorkspaceToBody();
  }

  private appendWorkspaceToBody(): void {
    const workspaceRef = this.cfr
      .resolveComponentFactory(WorkspaceComponent)
      .create(this.injector);
    workspaceRef.instance.workspaceService = this;

    this.appRef.attachView(workspaceRef.hostView);

    const domElem: HTMLElement = (workspaceRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>)
      .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

    document.body.appendChild(domElem);
  }
}
```

> Workspace Component

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-workspace",
  template: "{{workspaceService.name}}"
})
export class WorkspaceComponent implements OnInit {
  public workspaceService: WorkspaceService

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

To check the problem code, go to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b4teyg)

Comment: Instead of importing class inside service why can't you pass as a argument to appendWorkspaceToBody?

Comment: what will it change since it is only called from it's constructor

Comment: Yes it will get rid of cyclic dependency error. And You have to call it from component, instead of calling inside service

Comment: still I get a build warning for cyclic dependency

Comment: I have tried in the stackblitz, it's working fine:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qeqimh?file=src/app/workspace/workspace.service.ts

Comment: Check this for detailed explanation of why getting this error:https://angular.io/errors/NG0200

Answer (score 0):

The better solution I found for this problem is to write a separate service for component initialization which is executed from the module by providing in APP_INITIALISER.

Module

```
// @dynamic
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent, WorkspaceComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    WorkspaceService,
    WorkspaceInitializeService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (service: WorkspaceInitializeService) => () =>
        service.appendWorkspaceToBody(),
      multi: true,
      deps: [WorkspaceInitializeService]
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Service

```
@Injectable()
export class WorkspaceService {
  name = "John";
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Init Service

```
@Injectable()
export class WorkspaceInitializeService {
  constructor(
    private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private injector: Injector
  ) {}
  appendWorkspaceToBody(): void {
    const workspaceRef = this.cfr
      .resolveComponentFactory(WorkspaceComponent)
      .create(this.injector);

    this.injector.get(ApplicationRef).attachView(workspaceRef.hostView);

    const domElem: HTMLElement = (workspaceRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>)
      .rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;

    document.body.appendChild(domElem);
  }
}
```

To check the solution code, go to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2tgitt)